# System.OutOfMemoryException in asp.net Web API with Angular 2

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I am using Angular 2+ with asp.net Web API. I have C# DataTable which is returning to Angular 2+. I am using Post method for it.

But When I return my large data (85K+). It is returning fine from asp.net web API. But, It is giving me an error of "System.OutOfMemoryException" in browser. And, I am not able to receive the in Angular 2+.

I need to know if I am missing something, If yes then what. And, I want all record and in one short.

Comment: Although you use Angular, the issue isn't related to Angular. I'm removing the tag.

Comment: You're missing all of the relevant server code in your question.

Comment: Hii john What you want to know about server code. please do let me know. I will provide it.

Comment: You say you're returning "large data" and that the server is failing due to "System.OutOfMemoryException". You need to find the relevant code which is triggering this exception. Presumably you're not streaming the data to the client in some way, and are instead loading it fully into server memory.

Comment: With such a large data you should think about data virtualization, this might help to load only that part which user is viewing and performance will be better.

Comment: can you give me a link or demo of data virtualization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way of loading data. As I am using HTTP to bring data from asp.net web API. so, I am bringing data into packets using custom observable. It solved my problem of bringing all data at a time and resolved the error "system.outofmemoryException".